# Editing a big JSON file containing arrays of big objects

Tags: json, vim, editing

I have many big JSON files containing arrays of objects, arrays of arrays etc.
I need to add more objects into the JSON files (keeping the schema of the file same). and modify the fields of JSON files systematically but not sure how to do it in an intelligent way.

e.g.:
JsonFile:

```
{ 
  "objA": [
          { "f1"= 1, ...  } , {"f2"=2,..}, ...}
          ]
.
.

}
```

Now if i need to add 100 more objects in objA Array with "f1" fields incremented from the last one. How to do that fast using vim. I am pasting the object using 100p but incrementing the field manually which i think could be done in a better way. I need to do this often and with different fields. Any suggestion using VIM tool or any other tool , i would really appreciate.

Thanks.
PG.

Comment: By editing a JSON file in Vim, you choose to treat it as text so there is no array or object or whatever. Only *text* with uneven alignment and spacing and so on. As a smarter alternative, you could use a scripting language and use JSON as what it is supposed to be: data. But whatever method you choose, you will have to make your file valid JSON first because inserting any number of incorrect `"fx"= x` doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: seems to me that [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is the tool to do this.